# Cartoon about a girl and her friends and two teams

Tags: story-identification, magic, cartoon, magical-creatures

I watched a cartoon show last year.

It's about a teenage girl and her friends, I think part of a team. I remember something about team A or team B, daily combating magic and fantasy/magical creatures. If I remember correctly she is studying magic from her grandma and has a dragon as another mentor. I feel like I have the name on the tip of my tongue but can't remember it no matter what, and I have tried Googling everything I can think of. I think it is European, like French or Italian, and I believe her name is the title of the series.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Is there anything else you can remember about the show and its events? Was the animation 2D or 3D? Every little detail you can add will make it easier for us to identify the show you're looking for.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: 2D. Part of team B was a werewolf or part werewolf. I think she watched a vampire kid in one episode. Her grandma's place had a protective barrier. If I can remember anything else, i'll post it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is likely *[Tara Duncan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tara_Duncan:_The_Evil_Empress)*, a French animated show that debuted in 2010 on Disney XD, and is based on [the eponymous novel series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tara_Duncan).

[image: Title card for Tara Duncan]

> Tara is blonde with navy blue eyes, white wick as her ancestors and extraordinary powers (because she was genetically modified by a crazy dragon) . She has a rebellious spirit and a great need for freedom, as well as a tempestuous personality, which she makes it known quickly by charring those who are the object of her wrath.
>
> Tara Duncan discovers that she is a powerful "spellbinder," possessing magic powers. She was raised on Earth as an ordinary teenager by her grandmother and initially knew nothing of magic. Her adventures begin when she is 12 and take her to the planet Other World and beyond. Magic is present in those worlds, as are evil wizards, giants, "vampyrs," dwarves, elves, sirens, and two-headed business administrators.
>
> Tara's companions in her adventures include her fellow Earthling Fabrice and the friends she makes on OtherWorld: a half-elf called Robin M'angil, the licensed thief in training Caliban Dal Salan, a shapeshifting princess Gloria Daavil nicknamed "Sparrow", and a short-tempered but warm-hearted female dwarf named Fafnir.

The school has an "Alpha Team" and a "Beta Team".

Search terms of *animated series grandmother dragon mentor "team a"*

### Trailer

Answer (score 4):

Is it the [Life and Times of Juniper Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Life_and_Times_of_Juniper_Lee). Titular character Juniper Lee learns magic from her grandmother. She has another mentor who is a pug, not a dragon.

Comment: Juniper Lee is American though? It wouldn't really fit in with it being a French/Italian show.

Comment: no i remember that show and it's title. Art looked similar to Huntik or W.I.T.C.H. I tried looking under series the creators made for each series but didn't find it.